# networkx: nx.draw is not drawing

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am running a simple python script on my shell.
In the script I create a simple graph(2 nodes, 1 edge) and trying to draw it to my screen.

I do not get any error, but the graph is not showing

```
import matplotlib
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
nx.draw(G)
```

I don't get any error but there is no output.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
nx.draw(G)
plt.draw()
```

this works for me

Comment: It didn't work for me. I execute it on shell, Ubuntu.
@mikethebike on each environment do you run it?

Comment: I ran it in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Add `plt.show()` after your `nx.draw()`, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
import pylab
pylab.show()
```

as followed:

```
import pylab
import matplotlib 
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
nx.draw(G)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` also can help this problem. Not that you need it, but in case a future reader happens on this.